How to prove that the improper integral is uniformly continuous?
Let $f$ be a uniformly continuous and bounded function on $\mathbb{R}$, and let $g$ be a continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |g(x)| dx$ converges. Show that $$F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(xt)g(t) dt$$ is  uniformly continuous.
I tried to prove this by definition of uniform continuity, but I could not .

Pick $\varepsilon>0$ and define $C=\sup_{\mathbb{R}} \vert f\vert+1$. As
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \vert g(t)\vert dt <\infty$$
there exists $L>0$ such that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{-L} \vert g(t)\vert dt +\int_{L}^\infty \vert g(t)\vert dt<\varepsilon/(4C).$$
This means that that
$$\vert F(x)-\int_{-L}^L f(xt)g(t)dt\vert<\varepsilon /4.$$
In particular, we get for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$
$$ \vert F(x)-F(y)\vert <\varepsilon/2 + \int_{-L}^L \vert f(xt)-f(yt)\vert \cdot \vert g(t)\vert dt
\leq \varepsilon/2 +2L (\sup_{t\in [-L,L]} \vert g(t)\vert) (\sup_{s\in [-L,L]} \vert f(xs)-f(ys)\vert).$$
As $g$ is continuous, we get that its supremum on $[-L,L]$ is finite and we are left to prove that the factor with $f$ can be made small uniformly in the difference of $x$ and $y$.
We know that $f$ is uniformly continuous, thus, for every $\tilde{\varepsilon}>0$ there exists $\tilde{\delta}>0$ such that
$$ \vert \tilde{x}-\tilde{y}\vert \leq \tilde{\delta} \Rightarrow \vert f(\tilde{x})-f(\tilde{y})\vert <\tilde{\varepsilon}.$$
If $s\in [-L,L]$ then we have
$$ \vert sx-sy\vert \leq L \vert x-y\vert.$$
If we set
$$ \tilde{\varepsilon} = \frac{\varepsilon}{2\cdot(2L (\sup_{t\in [-L,L]} \vert g(t)\vert)+1) } $$
then we get for $L\vert x-y\vert\leq \tilde{\delta}$ that
$$ \vert f(sx)-f(sy) \vert < \tilde{\varepsilon}. $$
The previous inequality holds true for all $s\in [-L,L]$ and hence for $L\vert x-y\vert\leq \tilde{\delta}$ we get
$$  \sup_{s\in [-L,L]}\vert f(sx)-f(sy) \vert \leq \tilde{\varepsilon}.$$
Thus, for $\vert x -y\vert \leq \tilde{\delta}/L$ we get
$$ \vert F(x)-F(y)\vert<\varepsilon/2 +2L (\sup_{t\in [-L,L]} \vert g(t)\vert) (\sup_{s\in [-L,L]} \vert f(xs)-f(ys)\vert)
\leq \varepsilon/2+\varepsilon/2 =\varepsilon. $$
